# ListView + Resources > Image + Text

Tags: android, xml

i have this

```
setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                R.array.listOfCountries, R.layout.row));
```

and it makes the basic listview from this resources xml

```
<string-array name="listOfCountries">
        <item>Bulgaria</item>
        <item>Canada</item>
        <item>Croatia</item>
        <item>USA</item>
        <item>UK</item>
    </string-array>
```

but I need to add current image tu every country, for example to Bulgaria I want to add a bulagria's flag and so on.

But I need to have this string-array stores in resources because I want to make localizations for more languages.

Thank you

Comment: Below tutorial will help for your requirement **[Custom ListView](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) and [this](http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/custom-arrayadapter-with-with-different.html)** Video - [youtubeVideo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjAlNfa6obU) Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to create your own ListAdapter by subclassing BaseAdapter and overriding the getView(), getCount(), getItem(), etc methods.

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/

Create a class called Country like this:

```
public class Country {
   public String name;
   public int flagResourceId;

   public Country( String name, int flagResourceId ) {
      this.name = name;
      this.flagResourceId = flagResourceId;
   }
}
```

Then you can use that in your custom BaseAdapter, and bind that object into the View in getView().  What creates the List can be done either during onCreate(), or in an class within your Application.